# how to link a button to another .py file in python2.7

Tags: python, button, tkinter, hyperlink

How do I link a python button?

Basically I want a python button to execute another python file.

I am using Tk.

I've created this button and would like it to execute the script

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

    b = Button(toolbar, text="Travelling", width=9 )
    b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

mainloop()
```

How do I make this button execute another python script on click?

Comment: You will need to explain what library you're using and what sort of button you're referring to. Is this a GUI app or a web app, for example?

Comment: What does "opening up another python file" mean? Execute the python file as a script, open it in a text editor, or something else?

Comment: I assume he means execute the next script on the current data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want execute another python script use execfile():

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
def callback():
    execfile("script.py")
b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()
mainloop()
```